# jquery syntax to look for a hidden field in a form

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a form with a table in it.  In each row is a table cell with a hidden input item with the name of it starting with "hf_id_" followed by a number so that row 1's field has a name of "hf_id_1", row 2 is "hf_id_2" and so on.  I need to search all of these fields for a particular value but I'm not quite sure how to get to the hidden fields.  I know how to get to them when the full name is known but in this case I'm not sure if there's a way to get an array of these where name starts with "hf_id_".  Thanks.

Comment: I think I found it - $("input[name^='hf_id_']")

Answer (score 1):

You can search elements with `^` (starting with) and `$` (ending with), example:

```
$('input[name^="hf_id_"]');
```

So you can get all those elements like:

```
var elements = $('input[name^="hf_id_"]');
```

And you can iterate over them to search for a particular value like:

```
$('input[name^="hf_id_"]').each(function(){
  if ($(this).val() === 'search value here')
  {
     // found..........
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply use

```
  $('input[type="hidden"]');
```